# How to move tables location in lyx

Tags: lyx

I created a table in lyx (used insert - table) but how do I copy the table to another location ? When I select the table and try to copy it to another place in the document, it lost all the table format with only text left. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Start the selection *outside* the table. If you do that, the selection area will look like this:

[image]

Copy-pasting this will give a new table. If, on the other hand, you start the selection *inside* the table, making the selection area look like this:

[image]

you'll get the content of the table, not the table itself.

Comment: Thank you very much !